Field equations for systems violating local conservation rule
Is there a modified gravity theory which only allows for some weaker form of local conservation rule? Like in Einstein's gravity, equating $G_{\mu\nu}$ with $T_{\mu\nu}$ naturally leads to conservation rule because of divergence-free property of Einstein tensor. I was looking at the relativistic transport theory ( such as in this article https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(66)90207-7 ) , and it seems that SET is in general not conserved (equation 2.26):
$$\nabla_aT^{ab}=nq^b$$
where $q^a$ is momentum exchanged with the medium due to absorption/emission process. It doesn't look like one can manipulate the expression of $nq^a$ to define a new divergence free $T_{ab}$. In scenarios like these, how do we solve for Einstein's field equations?

I can't access the paper, but latin indices are usually referred only to the spatial part, which obviously is not conserved. If that is the case then: $nq^b =\nabla_aT^{ab} = \nabla_0 T^{0b}$, but is the full $\nabla_aT^{ab} - \nabla_0 T^{0b} $ which is zero.

When divergence of matter $T$ isn't zero, then within scope of theories with local conservation of energy and momentum, there has to be something else (fields interacting with matter, like EM field) that also has its $T$ divergence of which is exactly the opposite, so that net $T$ of both things has zero divergence (this works and can be checked for charged particles and EM fields). If net $T$ of everything is assumed to have non-zero divergence, this would fall outside, and be a theory where there is no local conservation of energy and momentum.

@JánLalinský So let's assume for the moment, systems which doesn't admit local conservation of energy and momentum. 1) Is it possible to have such system ? (I believe they cannot have a Lagrangian description otherwise it would be possible to derive the conserved SET). 2) Will such systems produce gravitational fields? It doesn't seem to be within the premise of GR, but I find it odd why only the conserved SET can produce curvature.  To the user LolloBoldo, I used the latin indices to mean space-time indices


yes, already in mechanics there are systems that do not conserve energy but still are described by a Lagrangian and Hamiltonian, for example, damped harmonic oscillator, described by Havas' Lagrangian. Noether charge corresponding to time symmetry (value of Hamiltonian) is conserved, but it is not energy.



in Einstein's theory, total T must be locally conserved, so if the model of matter is just a system with non-conserved T, we can't connect it to Einstein's theory and calculate how gravity is affected. Some other part would have to be added, which would make T conserved. Certainly it should be possible to formulate a theory where energy and momentum of matter and fields is not conserved, and still affects gravitation, but this would be different from Einstein's theory. For example, Newtonian gravity does not need energy and momentum of matter to be conserved.


@JánLalinský regarding 1) I think the requirement should be that one has a covariant lagrangian for the system, because the SET obtained from Einstein-Hilbert definition would be conserved for eg. even if the components do not have their usual meaning. For 2) I remembered that Newton-Cartan theory does have Ricci curvature equated to SET , so one can probably use that as an approximation. Ig that answers my question. Thank you for the responses

I don't understand your point that there should be a requirement of covariant lagrangian. If you're after exotic theories without conservation, one can imagine a theory without any Lagrangian. But indeed, the action-derived canonical T would be conserved even if this action described a non-conservative system whose actual energy-momentum T is not conserved. Agreed on Newton-Cartan theory, conservation of T does not matter there, all that matters for gravity is density of mass.
